# Session object is null after some time in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, session-variables, session-state, session-timeout

I have web application ASP.NET MVC 4. When user login to application, I writes his information to session as an object of class UserCtx. Previously, I create a cookie:

```
public ActionResult executeLogin(LoginModel model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);

                UserCtx userCtx = ds.SetUserCtx(model.UserName, model.Password);
                Session["UserCtx"] = userCtx;
                return Redirect(returnUrl ?? "/Offer");
            }
        else
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
    }
```

To make it easier to operate on an object held in the session, I created a static property, which I use in the application:

```
public class UserCtx
{
    public static UserCtx UserLogged 
    {
        get
        {
            UserCtx userCtx = ((UserCtx)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserCtx"]);
            return userCtx;
        }
    }
```

}

For example I often use this property in view:

```
@if (UserCtx.UserLogged.ADMIN)
{
   @Html.Partial("_gvNetLogPartial")
}
```

However, after some time, this variable is null, but I don't really know why this is happening. Moreover I have set timeout in web.config:

```
<sessionState timeout="30"/>
```

Also, I have filter on every controller that checks value of the session. Here is the filter:

```
public class CheckSessionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["UserCtx"] == null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        }
    }
}
```

This error may appear because I use a static property?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I developed a Web .NET application where I stored the information about the current logged-in user into a "static" `Session` object, exactly like your code.

However, I realized that this is an old-fashioned approach, used with the old ASP. Now, ASP.NET provides a better way to deal with the user object.

Instead of using a `Session` object, you should override the standard `User` object into `HttpContext`. I replaced my code by following this approach and it works perfectly.

Below, I'll recap the steps I did - I suggest you do the same.

First, you have to write the class that will store the information you need about the user. This is mine.

```
public interface ICustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    string Email { get; set; }
    string[] Roles { get; set; }
    int[] SalesmenId { get; set; }
    bool HasWritePermission { get; set; }
}

public class CustomPrincipalSerializeModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string[] Roles { get; set; }
    public int[] SalesmenId { get; set; }
    public bool HasWritePermission { get; set; }
}

public class CustomPrincipal : ICustomPrincipal
{
    private IPrincipal principal;

    public CustomPrincipal(IPrincipal principal, WindowsIdentity identity)
    {
        this.Identity = identity;
        this.principal = principal;
    }

    public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        //return (principal.IsInRole(role));
        if (Roles == null)
            return false;
        return Roles.Contains(role);
    }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string[] Roles { get; set; }

    public int[] SalesmenId { get; set; }

    public bool HasWritePermission { get; set; }
}
```

Then, edit the Global.asax so that, after that the user logs in, you replace the `User` object of the current `HttpContext` with an object of the custom type you defined at the previous step (see the very last instruction).

```
    protected void WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object source, WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Identity.IsAuthenticated && null == Request.Cookies.Get(CookieName))
        {
            CustomPrincipalSerializeModel cp = new CustomPrincipalSerializeModel();

            string username = e.Identity.Name;

            [...]

            // Set the data of the current user
            cp.Roles = [...];
            cp.SalesmenId = [...];
            cp.Email = [...];
            cp.HasWritePermission = [...];

            [...]

            // Serialize the cookie
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string userData = jss.Serialize(cp);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket formsAuthTicket =
                new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                            1,
                            username,
                            DateTime.Now,
                            DateTime.Now.AddHours(10), // The cookie will expire in 10 hours
                            false,
                            userData);
            var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(formsAuthTicket);

            // Store the cookie
            HttpCookie httpCookie = new HttpCookie(CookieName, encryptedTicket);
            Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
        }
    }

    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomPrincipal newUser = new CustomPrincipal(User, (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity);

        HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies.Get(CookieName);

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket formsAuthenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            CustomPrincipalSerializeModel ret = jss.Deserialize<CustomPrincipalSerializeModel>(formsAuthenticationTicket.UserData);
            newUser.Email = ret.Email;
            newUser.Roles = ret.Roles;
            newUser.SalesmenId = ret.SalesmenId;
            newUser.HasWritePermission = ret.HasWritePermission;
        }
        else
        {
            newUser.Email = null;
            newUser.Roles = null;
            newUser.SalesmenId = null;
            newUser.HasWritePermission = false;
        }

        Context.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal = newUser;
    }
```